# Twilio Remote video from Safari iPhone showing black-screen in Angular 5

Tags: ios, angular, twilio, twilio-video

iPhone safari version: 11.2.5

Chrome version: Checking for updates Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The connection is a peer to peer.

```
If I can give you an overview it's like -

Video is coming on iPhone from mac safari, Chrome, window laptop
Video is coming on Android Phone from mac safari, Chrome, window laptop
Video is coming on mac safari, Chrome, window laptop from Android Phone

Video is NOT COMING on mac safari, Chrome, window laptop from iPhone
```

Please let me know if you can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this issue

```
createLocalVideoTrack({
      video: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
    }).then(track => {
      if (this.localVideo) {
        const element = track.attach();
        this.renderer.data.id = track.sid;
        this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'width', '25%');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.localVideo.nativeElement, element);
        this.attachVideoClass();
      }
    });
```

Should be :

```
   this.roomObj.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(publication => {
      const element = publication.track.attach();
      this.renderer.data.id = publication.track.sid;
      this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'width', '25%');
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.localVideo.nativeElement, element);
    })
```

Comment: For some annoying reason Twilio continues to post the "createLocalVideoTrack" approach in their sample code, but it doesn't work for ios -- browser-clients receiving the video stream from iOS just show a black box. Your solution worked for me - thank you - and it drives me bonkers that it took so long for me to find it!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend reading through the [developing for Safari 11 article](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/developing-safari-11) which goes over a bunch of potential issues.

Comment: I already checked this...I am receiving audio but in case of video, the only black screen appears.

Comment: Is the Chrome browser you're using on the desktop? What version of Twilio Video are you using? Do you find your code works when testing with iOS Safari 13?

Comment: Chrome browser is on desktop and I am using Twilio-video v2.3.0. I tested with iOS Safari 13 sound and a black screen is coming.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to connect? I do not have issues connecting to Twilio Video on iOS Safari, so I'm wondering what you are doing differently.

Comment: What version of Twilio Video are you using?

Comment: Twilio-video v2.3.0

Comment: I see you're using the trackAdded and trackRemoved events from version 1.x. These are deprecated and I recommend you upgrade to track publication and subscription events. Check out the changelog here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/migrating-1x-2x#trackpublication.

Comment: I am attaching a video from function name "attachTracks"

Comment: Yes, but you are listening for the out of date `trackAdded` event. Do you see any errors in the console in Safari?

Comment: Thanks @philnash for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

Please check code:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { connect, createLocalTracks, createLocalVideoTrack } from 'twilio-video';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BaCustomPreLoader } from './baCustomPreloader.service';


@Injectable()
export class TwilioService {

  remoteVideo: ElementRef;
  localVideo: ElementRef;
  previewing: boolean;
  msgSubject = new BehaviorSubject("");
  roomObj: any;

  roomParticipants;

  private renderer: Renderer2;
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
    private baCustomPreLoader: BaCustomPreLoader) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }

  getToken(username): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('/abc', { uid: 'ashish' });
  }

  microphone = true;

  mute() {
    this.roomObj.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function (
      audioTrack
    ) {
      audioTrack.track.disable();
    });
    this.microphone = false;
  }


  unmute() {
    this.roomObj.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function (
      audioTrack,
      key,
      map
    ) {
      audioTrack.track.enable();
    });
    this.microphone = true;
  }


  connectToRoom(accessToken: string, options): void {
    connect(accessToken, options).then(room => {
      this.roomObj = room;

      if (!this.previewing && options['video']) {
        this.startLocalVideo();
        this.previewing = true;
      }

      this.roomParticipants = room.participants;
      room.participants.forEach(participant => {
        this.attachParticipantTracks(participant);
      });

      room.on('participantDisconnected', (participant) => {
        this.detachParticipantTracks(participant);
      });

      room.on('participantConnected', (participant) => {
        this.roomParticipants = room.participants;
        this.attachParticipantTracks(participant);

        participant.on('trackAdded', track => {

          const element = track.attach();
          this.renderer.data.id = track.sid;
          this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'height', '100%');
          this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'max-width', '100%');
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.remoteVideo.nativeElement, element);
          this.attachVideoClass();
          this.baCustomPreLoader.hide();
        });
      });

      // When a Participant adds a Track, attach it to the DOM.
      room.on('trackAdded', (track, participant) => {
        this.attachTracks([track]);
      });

      // When a Participant removes a Track, detach it from the DOM.
      room.on('trackRemoved', (track, participant) => {
        this.detachTracks([track]);
      });

      room.once('disconnected', room => {
        room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(track => {
          track.track.stop();
          const attachedElements = track.track.detach();
          attachedElements.forEach(element => element.remove());
          room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(video => {
            const trackConst = [video][0].track;
            trackConst.stop();  // <- error

            trackConst.detach().forEach(element => element.remove());

            room.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(trackConst);
          });



          let element = this.remoteVideo.nativeElement;
          while (element.firstChild) {
            element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
          }
          let localElement = this.localVideo.nativeElement;
          while (localElement.firstChild) {
            localElement.removeChild(localElement.firstChild);
          }
          this.router.navigate(['thanks']);
          setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          }, 1000)
        });

      });
    }, (error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
  }

  attachParticipantTracks(participant): void {
    participant.tracks.forEach(part => {
      this.trackPublished(part);
    });
  }

  trackPublished(publication) {
    if (publication.isSubscribed)
      this.attachTracks(publication.track);

    if (!publication.isSubscribed)
      publication.on('subscribed', track => {
        this.attachTracks(track);
      });
  }

  attachTracks(tracks) {

    const element = tracks.attach();
    this.renderer.data.id = tracks.sid;
    this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'height', '100%');
    this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'max-width', '100%');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.remoteVideo.nativeElement, element);
    this.attachVideoClass();
    this.baCustomPreLoader.hide();
  }

  startLocalVideo(): void {
    createLocalVideoTrack({
      video: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
    }).then(track => {
      if (this.localVideo) {
        const element = track.attach();
        this.renderer.data.id = track.sid;
        this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'width', '25%');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.localVideo.nativeElement, element);
        this.attachVideoClass();
      }
    });
  }

  detachParticipantTracks(participant) {
    this.detachTracks(participant);
  }

  detachTracks(tracks): void {
    tracks.tracks.forEach(track => {
      let element = this.remoteVideo.nativeElement;
      while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
      }
    });
  }

  attachVideoClass() {
    let remote = document.getElementById('remote');
  }
}
```